# Sort out specific levels in one column according to the values in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I just came into R so I am stuck in a very basic question.

Right now I have a dataset listing soccer players and their goals, I have reordered the goals in descending order, now I need to find the top five players according to their goals.

the dataset looks like this:

```
Player Goals
A        10
A        10  
B        10
C        9
B        8
C        7
A        7
D        6
E        6
F        5
```

How can I sort out the top 5 players using the `dplyr` package?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one. If you could provide your data with `dput()` we could improve the code, Note: You have got ties in your dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  top_n(5 )
```

OR

```
df %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  slice_max(Goals, n=5)
```

```
  Player Goals
1      A    10
2      B    10
3      C     9
4      B     8
5      C     7
6      A     7
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` option:

```r
df <- read.table(text="Player Goals
A        10
A        10  
B        10
C        9
B        8
C        7
A        7
D        6
E        6
F        5", header = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(desc(Goals)) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 5L)
#>   Player Goals
#> 1      A    10
#> 2      B    10
#> 3      C     9
#> 4      B     8
#> 5      C     7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Much appreciate for the answers! I am not sure if I read the question wrong...as I understood, the final result should be five different players according to the rankiing of goals, meaning more than five lines until five different names appear. Is it correct or? 

Another question is what L mean in 5L?